# OpenLayers get position of newly created point

Tags: javascript, openlayers

I'm using

```
lineLayer.events.on({
    "vertexmodified": update
});
```

to get the line info once it's been modified. If a new point is added in between 2 existing points, is there a way to figure out the position of the new point in relation to everything else?

I'm updating a table based on the values of the line and need to know where to insert the new row.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can figure out the position of the vertex by looking at its parent collection:

```
var vertex = event.vertex;
var idx = vertex.parent.components.indexOf(vertex);
```

Comment: Nice catch, didn’t knew. Quite sure you can use without any risks, but just have to know that it’s not an APIProperty.

Answer (score 0):

You can’t (with actual OpenLayers code). I’d suggest you to get the whole geometry (you can access `event.feature.geometry` from your listener argument), and update the whole geometry at once rather than updating just a point.